# UBUNTU 20.04LTS crash when wakes from sleep and pixelated screen appears

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, crash

### I am using Dual boot on my dell G5 SE laptop. My screen crashes when it turns on from sleep I get a highly pixelated display. But my windows 10 works fine.

- I don't know how to fix this issue.

---

#PC specification

- Dell G5 SE
- ryzen 5 4600H
- AMD RADEON rx5600M
- UBUNTU 20.04LTS

---

What are all the graphic drivers should I install for Radeon rx5600M [when I turn on my ubuntu from sleep it crashes and below is the link of the picture.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mgn5pbBmTKINYj1MpE4fSsLRuGcA2Wj7?usp=sharing)

Can I have step by step solution coz I am new to Linux

```
                                              *Thanks In Advance*
```

Comment: Boot to an older kernel from the GRUB menu and see if it's better. Once booted, show me `uname -r`. Report back.

Comment: AMD Radeon driver at https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2. Check compatibility before installing.